# What is the proper way to stop and remove a docker container in Jenkins when using Docker Pipeline Plugin?

Tags: docker, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkins pipeline that builds and runs a Docker machine, not as an agent, but using a scripting block along with the Docker Pipeline Plugin methods `docker.build()` and `Image.run()`. This works fine but if the build fails, the docker container is left running! I currently have `Container.stop()` in a `post{ always{} }` block but it doesn't seem to work. I don't want ssh into my Jenkins server to delete the container after every build and I can't just leave it because it has a specific and necessary name. **How do I stop and rm the container regardless of failure of the build?**

My pipeline:

```
pipeline {
    agent none
    stages {
        stage('Checkout') {
            agent any
            steps {
                checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: '*/master']], doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false, extensions: [], submoduleCfg: [], userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: '<some credentials>', url: '<a git repo>']]])
            }
        }
        stage('Spin Up Receiver') {
            agent any
            steps {
                script { 
                    def receiver = docker.build("receiver",  "--rm centos7_receiver")
                    def receiver_container = receiver.run("-d -v ${PWD}/realtime_files/station_name/201707/f/20170710_191:/DSK1/SSN/LOG0_f/17001 --network='rsync_test' --name='test_receiver'")
                }
            }
        }
        stage('Run Tests') {
            agent { dockerfile { args '-v /etc/passwd:/etc/passwd --network="rsync_test"' } }
            steps {
                sh "python ./rsyncUnitTests.py"
            }
        }
    }
    post {
        always {
            script { 
                receiver_container.stop()
            }
        }
        failure {
            sendEmail('foo@bar.com')
        }
        changed {
            sendEmail('foo@bar.com')
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've discovered the answer. You must declare the variable (`def receiver_container`) for the docker machine _outside_ of the `pipeline`. Then you can call it from anywhere in the pipeline and it will be recognized.

Comment: Could you provide your solution as an answer to your own question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a working solution. You simply have to define a variable for the container *outside* the main pipeline. Then you can use it anywhere in the pipeline to start or stop the container. In particular, you can remove the container in `post{ always{ } }`.

```
def receiver_container
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Checkout') {
            agent any
            steps {
                checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: '*/master']], doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false, extensions: [], submoduleCfg: [], userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: '<some credentials>', url: '<a git repo>']]])
            }
        }
        stage('Spin Up Receiver') {
            agent any
            steps {
                script { 
                    def receiver = docker.build("receiver",  "--rm receiver_docker")
                    receiver_container = receiver.run("-d -u 0:0 -v /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/RsyncRealtime/jenkins_rt:/DSK1/SSN/LOG5_F/17191 --network='rsync_test' --name='test_receiver'")
                }
            }
        }
        stage('Run Unit Tests') {
            agent { 
                dockerfile { 
                    args '-u 0:0 -v /etc/passwd:/etc/passwd --network="rsync_test"'
                } 
            }
            steps {
                sh "sshpass -p 'test' ssh anonymous@test_receiver ls -l /DSK1/SSN/LOG5_F/17191"
                sh "python ./rsyncUnitTests.py"
            }
        }
    }
    post {
        always {
            script { 
                receiver_container.stop()
            }
        }
        failure {
            sendEmail('foo@bar.com')
        }
        changed {
            sendEmail('foo@bar.com')
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This does work and is verified but @PlinioSilveira answer is cleaner I think.

Answer (score 4):

You can use Image.withRun() instead of Image.run().

> Image.withRun[(args[, command])] {…}
>
> Like run but stops the container as soon as its body exits, so you do not need a try-finally block.

Here other useful commands:
https://qa.nuxeo.org/jenkins/pipeline-syntax/globals#docker

Comment: Also, `Image.inside[(args)] {…}` allows for entire blocks of commands to be completed and then the container removed once it has finished.

Comment: But does it also delete the container afterwards?

Comment: When using `inside{}`, I get the log `$ docker rm -f 8f10dc0b3e`, so I believe it does delete the container afterward.