# Jenkins/Groovy: why does docker.image.withRun() fail where docker.image.run() does not?

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-docker

Here is a simplification of Jenkins declarative pipeline I'm working with:

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  stages {
    stage("demo") {
      steps {
        script {
          def co_url = 'https://bitbucket.company.com/scm/demo/prj.git'
          checkout( [$class: 'GitSCM',
                       branches: [[name: 'my_branch']],
                       doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false,
                       extensions: [[$class: 'RelativeTargetDirectory',
                                     relativeTargetDir: 'prj']],
                       submoduleCfg: [],
                       userRemoteConfigs: [[url: co_url]]] )
          dir(WORKSPACE + "/prj") {
            def img = docker.build("foo:1.0.0", "--target fubar .")
            def container = img.withRun()
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Why does the line `def container = img.withRun()` generate this error:

```
Scripts not permitted to use method groovy.lang.GroovyObject invokeMethod java.lang.String java.lang.Object (org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.workflow.Docker$Image withRun). Administrators can decide whether to approve or reject this signature.
```

...whereas `def container = img.run()` does not?

`withRun()` would have been preferanle because of its cleaner interface to [guarantee cleanup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45314736/what-is-the-proper-way-to-stop-and-remove-a-docker-container-in-jenkins-when-usi), but it is not an option for me to administratively allow selected scripts.

Comment: The method is probably blocked on your Jenkins sandbox, the other isn't. Has run() been approved in the past? See: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/managing/script-approval/

Comment: @MichaelKemmerzell - I don't see run() in the list of `Signatures already approved`...but I think I get the gist of what you're saying: either some default setting, or some administrative choice that I'm not privy to has made run() an allowed function, but not so for withRun() - thank you (but grateful if you have further details to share).

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but here's your answer:

`docker.withRun()` requires a block argument be passed to it; for example, here's something pulled from [the jenkins documentation](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/):

```
node {
    checkout scm
    /*
     * In order to communicate with the MySQL server, this Pipeline explicitly
     * maps the port (`3306`) to a known port on the host machine.
     */
    docker.image('mysql:8-oracle').withRun('-e "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-secret-pw"' +
                                           ' -p 3306:3306') { c ->
        /* Wait until mysql service is up */
        sh 'while ! mysqladmin ping -h0.0.0.0 --silent; do sleep 1; done'
        /* Run some tests which require MySQL */
        sh 'make check'
    }
}
```

In your example, you aren't passing it a block saying what to do with the container. You must pass that block argument; without it, the groovy implementation in Jenkins can't find the method.

Instead of assigning something to the return value of `withRun`, you should be doing something like:

```
      dir(WORKSPACE + "/prj") {
        def img = docker.build("foo:1.0.0", "--target fubar .")
        img.withRun() { container ->
            /* Here go commands that should happen while the container runs */
            /* Once we exit this block, the container is shut down */
        }
      }
```

Now you may ask, why didn't you get an error message that said something like "no such method" or "bad parameter types" or something vaguely related?

Because the Jenkins developers have decided that it's fine that misspelled method names or (as here) incorrect parameters generate this obscure security error, or at least that it's such a small problem that it isn't worth fixing the interaction between the Jenkins script sandbox and the standard way that groovy does method resolution.

It's been this way in Jenkins since at least 2016 and not documented anywhere I can find except a few stackoverflow answers; you just have to know that when you hit a security error about `groovy.lang.GroovyObject invokeMethod` not being allowed that usually means that you misspelled a method name or passed arguments of the wrong type.

Comment: Thank you -- in addition to answering the question, this reveals the reason behind a lot of "odd behavior" related to misspelled names/incorrect functions from my early days learning Jenkins/Groovy script!

Comment: See also https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-72620